# Convert Segmentation Fault Signal to C++ exception

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a C++ unit test class. What I want to do is to run a given set of input test files on another class (`simulator` class as in code below).

Assume, `runTest` function as shown below calls my required class on each test file.

```
void runTest(vector<string> testFiles)
{
        for(auto file : testFiles)
        {
                cout <<" Running test file:"<<file<<std::endl;
                simulator simulatorObj(file);
                simulatorObj.run();
        }
}
```

Now there are some input test files where the simulator class can generate a Seg fault (due to a bug in `simulator` class). Now I want to catch this seg-fault in my test class. Is there any way in which I can convert seg-fault signal to a C++ exception or something similar.

I tried using try catch block with generic exception but it didn't work. Also I am not able to think of any solution.

Please help.

Comment: *I tried using try catch block with generic exception but it didn't work* -- Not surprising, since seg faults are not C++ exceptions.

Comment: Yes. But is there any way I can detect them in C++ code? May be a callback function in case Seg fault is generated.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no C++ standard for handling segfaults. What platform are you using?

Comment: Unix. GCC compiler.

Comment: You need to see if your compiler has any sort of extension(s) to support reporting of segmentation faults.  Otherwise, C++ has no concept of catching exceptions that are not explicitly thrown using C++ syntax, i.e. the `throw` keyword.

Comment: @MayankJain Also, not all bugs produce seg faults.  So I don't know what real benefit you get out of catching a bug that (by chance) produces a segmentation fault, other than indicating you need to fix your program.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - I can have 1000 test files and let's say first test file fails due to some error in code. Even in this case I have to show to user saying test 1 failed and continue to next test file.

Comment: @MayankJain -- How do you know that the corruption caused by the failed test won't corrupt the further tests?  Maybe you should write a batch script to run the tests, and not code the whole test suite in one program?  Your program is compromised, IMO if you get a seg fault.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - I do agree with you and think what you are suggesting is better option. Thanks for suggestion. Although, I will keep the question open If any one has any solution for this.